# javascript post submit different from input submit click?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code

```
<html>
<include jquery>
<script>
  function crea()
  {
     var html = '<form method="get" id="popUpForm" name="popUpForm" action="form_ricorda_dati.php"><hr /><input type="hidden" name="mio" value="1" />input3<input type="text" name="input3" value="" /><br />input4<input type="text" name="input4" value="" /><br /><input type="submit" id="11" value="Procedi" /></form><br /><a href="" onClick="prova()">submit</a>';
     var div = document.getElementById('cont');
     div.innerHTML = html;
  }

  function prova()
  {
     $('#popUpForm').submit();
  }

</script>
<body>
< a href="#" onClick="crea()">lancia funzione JS</a><br /><br />
<div id="cont"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This code:**

1. When I click on `<a href="#" onClick="crea()">` it "shows" the form
   into the `<div id="cont">`
2. **Way 1:** When I click on `<a href=""
   onClick="prova()">submit</a>` it calls `$('#popUpForm').submit();`
   **Way 2:** Click on `<input type="submit" id="11" value="Procedi"
   />`

**Problem:**

1. If I click `<input type="submit" id="11" value="Procedi" />` I
   reload the page and see correct query string (form `action="get"`). In
   the reloaded page, *if* I "show" the form and click on the input I see the last
   input (browser autofill okay).
2. If I click `<a href="" onClick="prova()">submit</a>`, after, I
   don't see the query string. In the reloaded page if I "show" the form and
   click on the input I don't see the last input (browser autofill fails).

(I see this problem in Chrome and IE, but not in Firefox.)

**Goal**

The browser autofill should always show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that the HTML form you are creating with JavaScript was not in the browser's DOM at the moment the page was loading. You can fix this by placing the form's HTML into your `body` tag to be rendered in the DOM, and hide it with JavaScript until a user clicks the `crea` link.

The problem number **2** seems to be that your link ( `<a href="" onclick="prova()"...` ) might go to the url given in the `HREF` attribute. Since that attribute is empty, your page goes to itself.

To make things easier, you should keep your HTML form out of your JavaScript logic. Also since you are using jQuery, I have converted your functions to binds.

Working example in [JSFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CN7qh/).

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="url/to/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function(){
                var form = jQuery( '#form' ),
                    crea = jQuery( '#creaLink' ),
                    prova = jQuery( '#provaLink' );

                form.hide();

                crea.on( 'click', function(){
                    form.show();
                });

                prova.on( 'click', function(){
                    form.submit();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#" id="creaLink">lancia funzione JS</a>
        <br />
        <br />
        <div id="form">
            <form method="post" id="popUpForm" name="popUpForm">
                <hr />
                <input type="hidden" name="mio" value="1" />
                input3
                <input type="text" name="input3" value="" />
                <br />

                input4
                <input type="text" name="input4" value="" />
                <br />

                <input type="submit" id="11" value="Procedi" />
            </form>
            <br />
            <a href="#" id="provaLink">submit</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>​
```

Comment: **TRiG** : tnx for post fix ;) . **Bob Kruithof** : ok I understand the problem. The form must be contained in the html page. I think I will use the property "display: none" (css) to make it invisible. Very thanks !! (ps: i test it: firefox ok , chrome ok, ie fail. I must to see ie option :-o )

Answer (score -1):

It might not be a good idea to depend on browser's autofill as different browsers may have different behaviors. Now if I am correct in assuming that you want the values to be present in the fields even after the form data is received and processed at the server, then I would suggest you to make use of AJAX techniques. Send the form data in the background to the server and show only the result once you receive the response.

Comment: More of a comment than an answer.

Comment: My idea was to use a field <input> as login and password as the other. in this case this method can be useful. anyway thanks for your idea